# Drupal 7 print content field in search results

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm using drupal 7, with apache solr...

I want to print a content field in the search results...Sounded easy enough,

I placed this function in a custom module:

`function module_name_apachesolr_modify_query(&$query, &$params) {
    $query->params['fl'] .= ',im_field_name';
  }`

I verified that the field name was correct in /admin/reports/apachesolr. I enabled the module, and everything so far looked correct.

Then in search-result.tpl.php I've done several variations of,

`<?php print render($content['im_field_name']); ?>`

With no success...I figured i might be doing something stupid. I'll keep plugging away at it, but any help is very appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently learning this and I was looking for the same thing, but managed to get it working. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be much documentation around for Drupal 7, but there is a small chapter about it in **The Definitive Guide to Drupal 7** book.

I used **hook_apachesolr_query_alter()**, for example:

```
function MODULE_apachesolr_query_alter(&$query, &$params, $caller) {
    $query->addParam('fl', 'im_field_name');
}
```

Adding the above meant it was now visible in the preprocess function for the template, so I did the below:

```
function THEME_preprocess_search_result(&$vars) {
    $vars['im_field_name'] = $vars['result']['fields']['im_field_name'][0];
}
```

Then it was available to the template:

```
<?php if ($im_field_name) : ?>
    <?php print $im_field_name; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend checking out the [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) module, for those wanting to customize the way search results are displayed by Apache Solr. It provides a high level of customization of search pages, including those generated by Apache Solr. Check out this screencast:

[Display Suite for Drupal 7 - Part 5: search display](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rn3e91C_2jw)